# Carrierwave + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

Any idea how to use Carrierwave to upload images with Heroku.

I added this to the uploader file:

```
def cache_dir
  "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
end
```

but images still don't save! After uploading an image, it saves and once you refresh the page, the image breaks.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can use Heroku and upload images without 3rd party storage service like Amazon S3.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Heroku allows you store files inside tmp but just in order to send to a 3rd party service. Inside carrierwave uploader class you can set for example

storage :fog

instead of default :file and setup uploads to AWS S3. There are other options as well.

One thing is that if you are using a free tier instance on Heroku your upload needs to finish in abut a minute - I would recommend setup where you upload files directly to s3 account.

https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem on Heroku is not persisted. Only files uploaded through deployment mechanisms (git push) are "persisted". Others like the ones in your `"#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"` folder will be erased. That's why they are disappearing.

---

I have answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37361940/52317). Here is a quote:

Your dyno on Heroku has a "read-only" filesystem. In a sense, your files will not be persisted between your dyno restarts and there is no guarantee that they will persist between any two requests. Here is an [excerpt from the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#formation-dynos-vs-one-off-dynos):

> Each dyno has its own ephemeral file system, not shared with any other dyno, that is discarded as soon as you disconnect. This file system is populated with the slug archive so one-off dynos can make full use of anything deployed in the application.

You can use the `#{Rails.root}/tmp` folder as temporary folder, but you need to upload your files to some external storage (S3, some CDN, etc.). Heroku has some addons that makes it easy to handle.